# Run intellij idea project from command line

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea

I have quite massive project which was developed in intellij Idea. Now I have to be able to run it from command line, but there are too many libraries including maven dependencies are used.
Is there a way to get command line that is used by intellij idea when it runs a project?

Comment: The command IntelliJ uses to run the project is displayed on the first line in the Run tab (it is collapsed by default) when you run the project. Is that what you need?

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt what about with Gradle? what command line should we use?

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven you can do this:

```
mvn install
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.module.Main" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime
```