# Is there a way to get the classpath from a Intellij project in order to execute the project from the command line (terminal)?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, terminal

I have created a large Maven project in Intellij IDEA that uses many libraries and Maven dependencies, I now have to be able to run it from the command line (using Terminal in MacOS Mojave). Is there a way to get the classpath that Intellij uses when it runs this project? Or any other way to avoid manually going through and typing each dependency's path by hand?

This question: [Run intellij idea project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400893/run-intellij-idea-project-from-command-line)  asks exactly what I want to know but it was never answered... more accurately the one answer and one comment that are given don't work, at least when I tried them and apparently when the op tried them as well.